# What is the difference between Oracle's VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 datatypes?

Tags: oracle, datatypes

When migrating tables coming from other DBMSs to Oracle, one of the standard tasks is to [replace all `VARCHAR(n)` fields with `VARCHAR2(n)` fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151817.aspx) (provided n <= 4000).

Why does Oracle call this datatype `VARCHAR2` and not just `VARCHAR` like other DBMSs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It would seem that Oracle at one time had plans to give a different definition to **VARCHAR** than to **VARCHAR2**.  It has told customers this and recommends against using **VARCHAR**.  Whatever their plans were, as of 11.2.0.2 **VARCHAR** is identical to **VARCHAR2**.  Here is what [the SQL Language Reference 11g Release 2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50978) says:

> Do not use the VARCHAR data type. Use
>   the VARCHAR2 data type instead.
>   Although the VARCHAR data type is
>   currently synonymous with VARCHAR2,
>   the VARCHAR data type is scheduled to
>   be redefined as a separate data type
>   used for variable-length character
>   strings compared with different
>   comparison semantics.

The [PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference 10g Release 2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/datatypes.htm#sthref736) puts it this way:

> Currently, VARCHAR is synonymous with
>   VARCHAR2. However, in future releases
>   of PL/SQL, to accommodate emerging SQL
>   standards, VARCHAR might become a
>   separate datatype with different
>   comparison semantics. It is a good
>   idea to use VARCHAR2 rather than
>   VARCHAR.

The [Database Concepts 10g Release 2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#sthref3780) document says the same thing in stronger terms:

> The VARCHAR datatype is synonymous
>   with the VARCHAR2 datatype. To avoid
>   possible changes in behavior, always
>   use the VARCHAR2 datatype to store
>   variable-length character strings.

The Oracle 9.2 and 8.1.7 documentation say essentially the same thing, so even though Oracle continually discourages the use of **VARCHAR**, so far they haven't done anything to change it's parity with **VARCHAR2**.

Comment: I remember varchar2 in Oracle 8i, but I'm not sure if it was the same a varchar then.

Comment: It was.  See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76965/c10datyp.htm#703.

Comment: There are indications that at some point before 8i the definition may have been different.

Comment: I used to think there was a different length limit on `varchar` before version 8, but I can't find anything reputable to back this up and now wonder if it is just a myth.

Comment: @Jack Douglas - I can't find anything in the Oracle 7 documentation about that.  From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/dcommon/oin/indexj.htm >> Oracle 7 Server >> Server Concepts >> Oracle Datatypes (can't directly link to it) says pretty much the same thing as later versions.  In another section of the version 7 documentation it says that in version 6 Varchar and Varchar2 were synonyms for char.

Comment: I see in the section about changes between v6 and v7 that `varchar2` is a new reserved word, and from the SQL guide that it is limited to 2000 - I'm pretty sure it is a myth that they were ever different now, but I guess the size limit got a bump at v8 (for both)

Comment: I can not find anything about this in the  12.1.0.2.0 documentation. What is the **recommended** type to use with  12.1.0.2.0?

Comment: This is still true for 19c

Answer (score 26):

Currently, the two are synonymous.

VARCHAR is an ANSI standard data type but Oracle's implementation of the VARCHAR data type violates the ANSI standard by considering the empty string to be NULL (Oracle's implementation predates the ANSI standard).  As Leigh points out, Oracle has stated that the semantics of the VARCHAR data type may change in the future with respect to how the empty string is treated.  If and when that happens, the semantics of the VARCHAR2 data type will remain the same.  Using the VARCHAR2 data type is safer because you don't have to worry that some future version of Oracle will break your code by causing empty strings to no longer be considered NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the original SQL standard a VARCHAR was 255 characters, and Oracle were at least having a stab at standards compliance in those days.

Comment: That gives hope to see Oracle varchar3(max) in some years.

Comment: Sql-server had no problems increasing the allowed length from 255 to 8000 (and now even to max). Why did Oracle need a different datatype.

Comment: CLOB has different semantics to VARCHAR2

Comment: "*a VARCHAR was 255 characters*" - this is wrong. The SQL standard never imposed a maximum limit on `varchar` (or more precisely `character varying`)

Answer (score -2):

Currently VARCHAR2 optimises memory usage by using bytes based on the number of characters. That means, a VARCHAR2(10) variable can use 2,4,5,6 etc bytes of memory if it holds smaller number of characters.

Whereas VARCHAR is fixed size. A VARCHAR(10) will always hold 10 bytes of memory.

Comment: This is plain wrong. `varchar` is an *alias* for `varchar2` they both produce **exactly** the same table definition and structure. You are confusing `varchar` with `char` - the latter being fixed sizes and padded.